# Bug when trying to parse date in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I was trying to convert `April from 04 (MM)` to `Apr (MMM)` it turned back into `nil`, is this a known issue in iOS or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code for inspection:

```
NSString *dateString=@"2016-04-01";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@ == %@",dateString,stringFromDate);
```

when change `dataString=@"2015-04-01"` the `stringFromDate` returns `Apr`

This is my output:

[this is the log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCtQS.png)

> 2016-04-01 12:17:45.708[32172:2389414] 2016-04-01 == (null)
>
> 2016-04-01 12:17:47.446[32172:2389414] 2015-04-01 == Apr

Comment: Why aren't you logging myDate? dateFromString is a lot pickier than stringFromDate, so myDate is more likely the problem.

Comment: I'd check for invisible characters in your string.

Comment: What country are you in? That would help us to find the specific time zone you are using.

Comment: @Sulthan How would the timezone have *any* effect here? It seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: myDate object is nil .. i tried the code now, my time timezone is GMT+2 .. tonight its gonna be +3 btw

Comment: @Eiko See my answer. For example the DST change in Jordan happens `April 1 2016` at `0:00`, therefore this exact time does not exist (`23:59` becomes `1:00`).

Comment: @gnasher729 myDate return nil when dateString =@"2016-04-01";

Comment: All those problems arise because you're using a wrong data type. An NSDate is more than a date, it is a point in time. It's more or less under specified the way you construct it, filling it with defaults, which might result in an invalid date, hence "nil".

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a problem in your time zone. Note that when parsing a date without time, the time is assumed to be zero. However, some specific times don't exist, usually due to Daylight Saving Time changes (which happen in March around the world) or due to specific local time changes.

For example, in Jordan, the DST change is `Apr 1 2016, 00:00 => Apr 1 2016, 01:00`. That means that the time `Apr 1 2016, 00:00` does not exist because `March 31 2016, 23:59` becomes immediately `Apr 1 2016, 01:00`. If the date does not exist, date formatter must return `nil`.

You can usually fix the problem by using a preset GMT time zone that does not have this problem, e.g

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

or

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone].secondsFromGMT];
```

Note that since you are not parsing time, time zone differences shouldn't affect you.

**Steps to reproduce**

Set the time zone on your machine to Jordan time zone:
[image]

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-04-01";
NSDateFormatter* parsingFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
parsingFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

NSLog(@"Parsed: %@", [parsingFormatter dateFromString:dateString]); // "(null)"
```

with time zone fix:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2016-04-01";
NSDateFormatter* parsingFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
parsingFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
parsingFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

NSLog(@"Parsed: %@", [parsingFormatter dateFromString:dateString]); // "2016-04-01 00:00:00 +0000"
```

Comment: no man, something wrong with the parsing, its giving the myDate object as nil !

Comment: @AhmedAwad and did you try my code? Note that you have to add it *before parsing*.

Comment: Note that this might generally not always give the expected result, when both date formatters have different time zones set. This really isn't a case for NSDate, it's for date components. :)

Comment: @Eiko That's true but if your input is a string (e.g. date coming from server), then you don't really have an option to avoid `NSDateFormatter` and that means using `NSDate`. Using the same time zone for both formatters would be required of course.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it gives me null for year 2022, but years 2018,2020 it gives Apr ... weird!

```
    NSString *dateString=@"2022-04-01";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"+5:30"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@ == %@",dateString,stringFromDate);
```

[image]

UPDATE:

Please parse the string as this :
2016-04-01 01:00

Because of daylight saving in Jordan the clock will be shifted +1 hour so there's no time in the universe like this:
2016-04-01 00:00

This should resolve ur issues with the nil object.

Comment: myDate object is nil guys.. why is it nil?!

Comment: add this timezone `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];` as per sulthan answer , try once

Comment: tried it, doesn't affect anything as the myDate object is nil for some reason :(