# NSDateFormatter string is invalid

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

**SITUATION**

The app I'm maintaining has a rare but reoccurring issue parsing NSStrings into NSDates. I have been unable to replicate it locally, but our logs show that it is indeed happening for our users.

I found a lot of NSDateFormatter questions on StackOverflow, but none seem to be directly relevant so here I am.

**WHAT'S HAPPENING**

The error message on our logs is `“2016-04-19T17:30:00-0400” is invalid.` I used the `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` function to grab the error description. That is not the only date that is failing; there are multiple ones.

The date format being used is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ`.

If it helps, the project uses Mantle and the initial conversion that failed happened through the NSValueTransformer. The logging of the error is done separately from the NSValueTransformer.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- Tried a fallback solution where it attempted to parse the string once more into a date, but according to the logs the fallback hasn't had any effect
- Tried parsing the failed strings in a separate test project...and they all work
- Tried messing with timezone in the separate test project, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, especially since the timezone is already in the date string itself via ZZZZ. I looped through possible timezones via `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]`
- Tried messing with the NSLocale to no effect. I can't get it to fail in the separate test project. I looped through possible locales via `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`
- Tried messing with the NSCalendar to no effect. I manually used the calendars provided at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Calendar_Identifiers
- Tried seeing if it was a threading issue, but couldn't find any evidence that it's an issue. Given how the fallback solution is implemented though, it's very unlikely to be a threading issue.

**CODE**

Fallback code that doesn't work. Element is a Mantle object. rawWhenValue is a string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = kNSDateFormatterWhenJSONFormat; //yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ
NSDate *when = [dateFormatter dateFromString:element.rawWhenValue];
element.when = when;
```

Code used to grab the NSDateFormatterError.

```
NSDate *dateFallback;
NSError *err;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, element.rawWhenValue.length);
BOOL parsed = [dateFormatter getObjectValue:&dateFallback forString:element.rawWhenValue range:&range error:&err];
```

I'm at my wits end. Even a direction to look in would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: You say you've tried messing with timezone and locale. Have you logged `formatter.locale.localeIdentifier`, `formatter.timeZone.name`, and `formatter.calendar.calendarIdentifier` on the user's device?

Comment: Update your question with the actual code giving the error.

Comment: @robmayoff I will try that

Comment: @rmaddy Code snippets added!

Comment: Have you tried the `en_US_POSIX` locale identifier on the date formatter?

Comment: @Rich I wrote a brute force date formatter in a separate test project that tried every locale, and none of them failed. I did not try using the locale in live code though.

Comment: Locales don't work on problems with nonexistent times. What actually works is setting a time zone specified with GMT offset, .e.g `formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]`. That's actually mentioned in the documentation to provide safe parsing.

Comment: I am giving a detailed description of a similar error in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36332291/669586

Comment: @Sulthan The dateString in my case contains the timezone via ZZZZ though. In theory it should use that one no? I also wrote a brute force program checking one of those dates against every timezone ([NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]), and I still could not repro the issue. I suppose it couldn't hurt to set the timezone to secondsFromGMT:0 just in case. Hmm.

Comment: @na Unfortunately it does not work like that. The `ZZZZ` is parsing the time zone where the date was created and the time zone is specified only as a GMT offset. When the date is parsed, the offset is just added to it as a number and *then* there is a verification that the result date exists in your *local* time zone. In past I could not reproduce such issues with time zones created from names. Do you have any real date that has been causing the issue somewhere?

Comment: @Sulthan Oohh, so local timezone matters for verification that it exists still, and the time zones from names don't encompass all the time zones possible. Gotcha. Thing is, there are MANY dates that have this issue, two recent ones are 2016-04-21T17:30:00-0400 and 2016-04-22T16:00:00-0400, but there are far more.