# Converting string to date returns nil swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get the current date in this format **"YYYY MM DD"** by doing the following:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let stringDate = formatter.string(from: Date()) //1
let currentDate = formatter.date(from: stringDate)! //2
```

1- lets assume that today's date is 2018 03 30 in  this case stringDate = "2018 03 30" which is fine.

2- here it returns nil even though that I have used the same formatter that converted the current date to this format.

now I tried the code on playground i got the same results as the following screenshot:

[image]

what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: The above code is working on my machine. What do you have set in your localization settings?

Comment: I bet this will be connected to daylight saving time changes again. What is your time zone? Could it be Jordan?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes its Jordan ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332291/669586 which I answered exactly two years ago.

Comment: @Sulthan Many thanks man it worked now :)

Comment: @WaleedSaadJebreen I think the easist fix could be `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())` but I am not able to reproduce it on my machine so I cannot test. Basically you have to remove the use of default time zone which contains the Daylight saving time information.