# why Date will return nil when using correct format in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift4, date-format

so here is the string Date that I want to Convert

```
2019-03-22T00:00:00
```

and here is the problem 
[image: this crash will happen because the date is nil]

**Remember that I used "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" or "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" or "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" or yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ and some other similar formats**

Comment: Day light saving change in Persia. There is no midnight that day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331455/bug-when-trying-to-parse-date-in-objective-c . The question is for objective-c but the problem and solution is the same. You should always set locale and time zone. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: the problem is that the date will return nil when I used correct format

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi See the link above. When parsing internet dates, you *have* to set the locale and time zone.

Comment: I saw that But I can't understand objective c I now trying to get the date in my son in Date format

Comment: Use `DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` when parsing ISO8601/RFC3999 dates like this one with the `T` in the middle of it. Or use `ISO8601DateFormatter` and avoid all of this silliness.

Comment: @Rob Actually, using POSIX won't help here. Time zone is the culprit.

Comment: I understood that I have to set timeZone If I don't set that I will get the crash

Comment: @Sulthan - I know, that’s why it’s a comment and not an answer. That QA1480 you shared with us suggests `en_US_POSIX` as a ISO8601 invariant locale.

Comment: this problems will solve when using Time zone as you said thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1st april dates of 80s failed to parse in iOS 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284272/1st-april-dates-of-80s-failed-to-parse-in-ios-10-0)

Answer (score 4):

You have to set a time zone and locale when parsing internet dates:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
// necessary to avoid daylight saving (and other time shift) problems
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
// necessary to avoid problems with 12h vs 24h time formatting
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
print(dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-22T00:00:00"))
```

The default time zone contains information about daylight saving time and some specific times does not exist there. Instead, we have to use a generic time zone.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

22 March 2019 around midnight is the day & time when daylight saving change in Iran makes an hour non-existent.

The same can be achieved using [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter):

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = ISO8601DateFormatter.Options.withInternetDateTime.subtracting(.withTimeZone)
print(dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-22T00:00:00"))
```

Comment: More than likely, that date string should be stored/read in UTC, not some local timezone.

Comment: @Rob Hard to say if the date itself does not contain time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function might help

```
public func dateFormatter(strDate: String) -> String{
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
 let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
 return dateString
}
```

Comment: thanks you helped me to find the answer here is the answer let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()) let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate) dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fa_IR") as Locale? let pDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!) dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd" return pDate

Answer (score 1):

```
dateFormatter.isLenient = true
```

Ignores missing hours during daylight saving time offset

Comment: BTW here is more detailed answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284272/1st-april-dates-of-80s-failed-to-parse-in-ios-10-0